# how to allow for missing data in a text file

Tags: c++, vector, double

I have got a large file containing numerous sets of data, there are some blanks though marked "--" where for what ever reason the data hasn't been recorded. The rest of the data will be stored as double in a vector, my problem is how do i pick up the missing data and store this missing data as a zero? a snippet of my data file;

```
0    29.1     ---
0    65.9     ---
2    56.5     ---
6    19.7    44.3
9    69.8    64.9
11   118.6   64.8
7    35.7    64.1




if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int count = 0;
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
      getline (myfile,line);
      /*if (line == "---")
        {
        sun(0.0);
        }*/
      if (count > 6) 
      {

      std::istringstream buffer(line);
            int month;
            double  rain, sun;
            if (buffer >> month >> rain >> sun)
            {
                Weather objName = {month, rain, sun};
                data_weather.push_back(objName);       
            }
      }
      count++;
    }
    myfile.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the data as a string one line at a time. Check if it's "--". If yes then same 0.0, if no then convert to a double and save the double.

```
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    if (line == "--")
    {
        save(0.0);
    }
    else
    {
        istringstrleam buf(line);
        double value;
        if (buf >> value)
        {
            save(value);
        }
        else
        {
            error("could not convert value");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using istringstream to do the conversion from string to double.

**UPDATE**

Based on the new information about the file format in the question the following should work (but it's untested code).

```
string line;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    if (count > 6)
    {
        int month;
        double rain, sun;
        std::string sun_as_string;
        std::istringstream buffer(line);
        if (buffer >> month >> rain >> sun_as_string)
        {
            if (sun_as_string == "--")
            {
                sun = 0.0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::istringstream buffer2(sun_as_string);
                if (!(buffer2 >> sun))
                {
                    // couldn't convert the sun value, so just set to zero
                    sun = 0.0;
                }
            }
            Weather objName = {month, rain, sun};
            data_weather.push_back(objName);       
        }

    }
    ++count;
}
```

It's the same basic idea as before, read the sun value as a string and only convert it to a double if it's not "--".

Comment: is there an example section of code i could refer to? to help me do this

Comment: where and how do i define save?

Comment: That depends completely on what you are trying to do. Just replace 'save' with whatever code you are currently using (same for 'error'). I didn't mean to imply that you had to have functions called save and error, just that was where you should save the value or report the error.

Comment: i have already declared my double "sun" for this particular column of data. basically i need, if (line == "--") //sun will equal 0.0?

Comment: see above, im nearly there just need to sort out the sun(0.0), its not quite right

Comment: So what do you want to do when the line is "--"? Orginally you said you wanted to store a zero, but now I see that you are storing three values. Do you want to store 0, 0, 0?

Comment: please see above, i have updated the info from my data file, the blank data is only in my column for sun, where there is "---" i just want it storing as 0.0

Comment: OK well, that's a bit more complicated, and the code I posted won't work. I'm busy right now, I'll try to update later.

Comment: @ thanks, it does make sense what youve done there, im getting 2 errors though, error C2374: 'buffer' : redefinition; multiple initialization and error C2088: '>>' : illegal for class

Comment: @jaylad That error means you've declared buffer twice. That's not happening in my code so I guess you have something slightly different from what I had.

Comment: i had done by mistake, above youre first line of string line;.......will i have if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    int count = 0;
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {

Comment: `while (myFile.good()) { getline (myfile,line);` is not the best (this has been asked and answered many times on SO). I would prefer `while (getline(myfile, line)) {` as I have it. The problem with the way you have it is that it only tells you that myfile is good **before** you do the getline, that doesn't guarantee that the next getline will work. What you really want to know is whether getline succeeded. That's what `while (getline( ... ` does.

Comment: yeah that makes sense,  i think I've cracked it, thanks for you're help!

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a slightly different alternative that doesn't explicitly check that the line is `--`, it just sees that it's not a valid `float`.

You can simply read out each line one at a time with `std::getline`, which will only stop once you reach the end of the file. You can attempt to extract from each line into a `float` (or `double`) that you have initialized to `0`. If the extraction fails, the value will still be `0`.

```
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
  std::istringstream ss(line);
  float f = 0.0f;
  ss >> f;
  results.push_back(f);
}
```

Comment: Will work because the OP have `"--"` in the missing entries, but can't be used if the user may attempt to parse value out of range as then the result (`f` in the code snippet in this answer) will be changed.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Indeed. It's just a simple solution to the particular problem given in the question, not intended to be robust to changes!